# Generic template parameter placeholders

Tags: c++, c++20

To prevent cost of clarity, which this stripped down example doesn't really do any justice. How can I write function declaration `g()` without a deduced return type (which includes type-constrained return types) and without having to resolve the return type of `c1` or `f()` more than once (even in an unevaluated context)?

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct s { using t = T; };

inline constexpr auto c1 = []{ return s<class a>{}; };
inline constexpr auto c2 = []{ return s<class b>{}; };

template<typename T>
constexpr auto f(s<T> (*c)()) -> s<T>
{ return c(); }

static_assert(sizeof(f(+c2)));
static_assert(sizeof(f(+c1)));

constexpr auto g() -> s<typename> // ideal but not supported
{ return f(+c1); }
constexpr auto g() -> s<decltype(c1())::t> // resolves return type twice
{ return f(+c1); }
constexpr auto g() -> s<decltype(f(+c1))::t> // resolves return type twice
{ return f(+c1); }

static_assert(sizeof(g()));
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3E67z55Gn)

Comment: Why do you want to avoid `constexpr auto g()  { return f(+c1); }` ?

Comment: *"without having to invoke `c1` or `f()` more than once (including unevaluated contexts)?..."*  **`decltype` doesn't actually "invoke" the function so  this requirement doesn't seem logical.**

Comment: @user12002570 It's due to cost of clarity (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tnl7FnwJ2Uw&t=2583s). Obviously, the stripped down example posted here doesn't do the real problem at hand any justice.

Comment: You should add that reason in the question.

Comment: Also, so instead of saying "invoke" you meant "writing"? Like you don't want to repeat what you wrote twice instead of invoking.

Comment: @user12002570 I'm not sure how to phrase it correctly (invoking/writing/resolving), but there can be a compile-time cost involved which I want to prevent (doing searches in compile-time with recursive functions which, the compiler doesn't cache).

Comment: @303: "*but there can be a compile-time cost involved which I want to prevent*" Um... how *else* is the compiler going to get an answer? You're either asking the compiler to look at the `return` statement to determine the type, or you're asking the compiler to evaluate a type expression to determine the type. Both of those are going to involve a "compile-time cost".

Comment: @303: Also, optimizing for compile-time performance is way harder than runtime. You have no idea whether deducing a return type from a `return` is slower or faster than using a type expression like `decltype` or of something else. Detecting which is faster or slower requires complex profiling, and it will likely vary a lot from compiler to compiler.

Comment: @NicolBolas 
Unfortunately, I can't easily rewrite this question/example to make more sense without introducing too many other factors that will come into play that I don't want to linger on. The hypothetical code with return type of `s<typename>` would be ideal in this situation, even if that actually still requires some form of return type deduction. Perhaps I should've directed this question instead as to why this feature of the Concepts Technical Specification didn't make it in C++20. I guess I just wanted to make sure I wasn't overlooking some sort of trick that I could use.

Comment: @303: "*why this feature of the Concepts Technical Specification didn't make it in C++20*" This is part of what I don't understand. You say that you don't want it to be deduced, but that hypothetical syntax would *still* be deduction. It's just deduction with a constraint; that the deduced type must be an instantiation of a template. The compiler would still have to do whatever work is needed to figure out what the *actual* return type is whenever you do something with it. So it would offer zero compiler performance benefit over just using deduction.

Comment: @NicolBolas The requirement of having no return-type deduction isn't there to prevent unnecessary compile-time cost. It's there because introducing type-constraints can only be done with the help of concepts, which, unlike templated types, functions, variables, and aliases, can't be limited to the private scope of a class. They also introduce complexity and bloat that outweigh the cost of clarity, at least, to my liking. Unfortunately, it seems when trying to limit the scope of a question to such a narrow space where there happens to be no straight forward answer, XY-problems start to appear.